# Unable to click on an item in Modal dialog using Selenium Java Script

Tags: java, html, selenium, dom, selenium-chromedriver

My UI Looks like:

[image]

My HTML looks like

[image]

I am unable to click on an item which is on modal dialog using selenium web driver.

I have tried below code

```
            List<WebElement> allBrancheRows=driver.findElements(By.xpath("table[@id='body_ucLookup1_grdData']tr"));

            for(int i=2;i<=allBrancheRows.size();i++)
            {
                WebElement BranchColumn=driver.findElement(By.xpath("table[@id='body_ucLookup1_grdData']tr["+i+"]td[3]"));
                if(BranchColumn.getText()=="NSW")
                {
                    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
                    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", BranchColumn);
                    BranchColumn.click();
                    break;
                }
            }

i have tried using click() method as well before using JavaScript. Even this has not worked.
Please advise
```

Comment: do not use images of source code. Please post the code itself.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Use this xpath it should work.

```
//table[@id='body_ucLookup1_grdData']//tr["+i+"]/td[3]
```